# Kubernetes: Expose only single pod of StatefulSet

Tags: networking, service, kubernetes, kubectl, statefulset

For for a StateFul set, I can access its pods via a headless service internally.

I think, it would make sense, to have an easy way to expose also single pods externally (since the pods usually have a state and therefore loadbalancing over them makes no sense).

So far, I found no straight forward way to do that.
Even doing `kubectl expose pod pod-1 --type NodePort` gives me a service which balances over all pods.
Is there a reason why this is like this or is there a nice way to access single pods.

Comment: Are you running multiple instance of state full set in your cluster?

Comment: I have multiple replicas (e.g. 3), i.e. pod-1, pod-2 and pod-3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expose a specific `Pod` in a `StatefulSet` externally by matching on the `statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name` label.

For example, if your `StatefulSet` is named `app` and you want to expose port 80 from the first `Pod` as a `Service`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-0
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: app-0
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Answer (score -1):

I don’t see they way to distribute the load to single pod.   If you want to client keep this session with one pod you can define service `sessionAffinity: ClientIP`. this will send established client traffic same pod.

Comment: From inside my Cluster, i can access each pod individually. So, I don't get the point why this makes no sense for access from outside the Cluster.

Comment: I am assuming Inside the cluster your using POD IP to access the pods correct? or your using service IP access the pod?

Comment: Actually, I am accessing the pods over the headless Service by their DNS names. So in the end, this should be the Service IP, I guess?